# How can I rotate childrens nodes with parent node in cocos2dx?

Tags: c++, transformation, cocos2d-x, tree

Consider the following code...

```
cocos2d::Node* parent = cocos2d::Node::create();
cocos2d::Node* child = cocos2d::Node::create();
parent->addChild(child);
parent->rotate(-90.0f); // But its not affecting the child position
```

When I am rotating the parent node by an angle, It's not affecting the child node position. How can I get it right? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use `setRotation()` method instead of `rotate()`